Jekyll: disable or fix tables
I write some simple math in Jekyll, like P(D|θ) etc. The Jekyll's Markdown parser takes 'pipe' (the vertical line) as a marker for the border of a table column. Sometimes. Sometimes not. This is unpredictable and this is annoying. This happens even in display-style equations.
Is there any way to fix it or to disable tables at all?
UPD I'm using kramdown parser, it's default.
The example page is as follows:
---
layout: post
title:  "Lol"
---
Example: P(θ|D) = L(D|θ) π(θ) / Z

Inline math is broken: $$P(θ|D) = L(D|θ) π(θ) / Z$$

But this one is OK: $$E = m c^2$$

Display-style:

$$P(θ|D) = L(D|θ) π(θ) / Z$$


UPD2 I lied. Pipes are OK in display-style math. But inline math feels bad.
UPD3 I've also tried CommonMark as a parser. It's more smart on tables but it makes two more things wrong (or I just couldn't prepare it well): (a) only displaystyle latex is allowed; (b) backslashes must be escaped with backslashes.
Thanks.

please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

same here... may workaround is to add a newline (but not an empty line) before the $$ ... or use some "latex" macros

Without an example of the issue I can suggest that you try two things:

Use the HTML entity code instead of the actual pipe character. The pipe character's code is &#124;. Your formula would look like this P(D&#124;θ)
The other option would be to wrap your content with "raw" tags, like so:

{% raw %}
This is the formula P(D|θ)
{% endraw %}


Thank you for the comment. Please, see the example I've added to the post.
